# dafa of flink`s source operator from kafka is nonuniform

Tags: stream, apache-kafka, apache-flink, bigdata

There is a topic of kafka which has 9 partitions. My flink job need to consume the topic to do ETL and sink data to another topic. So my source operator of flink job parallelism is configured 9. The flink cluster has 3 task manager, and every task manager have 3 source operator. But dafa of flink`s source operator from kafka  is nonuniform.

the source operator code：

```java
env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer09<byte[]>(topic, new DeserializationSchema<byte[]>() {
    @Override
    public byte[] deserialize(byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
        return bytes;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEndOfStream(byte[] bytes) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public TypeInformation<byte[]> getProducedType() {
        return PrimitiveArrayTypeInfo.BYTE_PRIMITIVE_ARRAY_TYPE_INFO;
    }
}, props)).setParallelism(9);
```

I attach the monitor screenshot below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIL7G.png)

what may I do to enhance this defect?

Comment: Is the data spread uniformly across all 9 Kafka partitions? If this is not the case, then this is not possible.